# How do I get around the error message popping up

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a basic brick breaker game in python using Tkinter. I have figured out how to delete the blocks, but am getting an error when the ball and brick collide. It always says that the index is out of range. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.block1 = block1
        self.block2 = block2
        self.block3 = block3
        self.block4 = block4
        self.block5 = block5
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3 
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
        if self.hit_block(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3


    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def hit_block(self,pos):
        block1_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block1.id)
        if pos[2] >= block1_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block1_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= block1_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block1_pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(self.block1.id)
                return True

        block2_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block2.id)
        if pos[2] >= block2_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block2_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= block2_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block2_pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(self.block2.id)
                return True

        block3_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block3.id)
        if pos[2] >= block3_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block3_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= block3_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block3_pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(self.block3.id)
                return True

        block4_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block4.id)
        if pos[2] >= block4_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block4_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= block4_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block4_pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(self.block4.id)
                return True

        block5_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block5.id)
        if pos[2] >= block5_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block5_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= block5_pos[1] and pos[3] <= block5_pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(self.block5.id)
                return True
        return False




class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0




class Block:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 50, self.y + 20, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)




block1 = Block(canvas, 50, 50, 'orange')
block2 = Block(canvas, 90, 50, 'yellow')
block3 = Block(canvas, 130, 50, 'green')
block4 = Block(canvas, 170, 50, 'blue')
block5 = Block(canvas, 210, 50, 'violet')
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, block1, block2, block3, block4, block5,'red')



while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: you should keep blocks on list and then use as `block[0]`, etc. And with `for` loop function `hit_block` will be much shorter. BTW: canvas has function `find_overlapping` which you can use to check collisions - instead of all `pos[2] >= block4_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block4_pos[2]:`

Comment: first rule: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback) - there are many usefull information. We can't read in your mind to see this message and don't expect that we will run code to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when a block is deleted, its coordinates no longer exist.

What you want to do is something like this, for all of the blocks:

```
if block1_pos and (pos[2] >= block1_pos[0] and pos[0] <= block1_pos[2]):
```

This will make sure that the block exists before it is checked.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct that I had to put in parentheses.